# Angular Unit testing with MatDialog - Error: <spyOn> : open has already been spied upon

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing

I create a html file with button. After onClickEvent poll appears and next, after click on button "submit" dialog window closes and I would like to call next methods.

TS.file:

```
openDialogWindow() {
const dialogRef = this.dialogWindow.open(PollComponent, {
  width: '400px',
  height: '400px',
  data: getData()
});

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
  if (result.status == 'VALID') {
    answerForm = result;
    this.callNextFunction();
  }
});
```

}

and then I created unit test in spec.ts file:

```
it('should call dialogwindow and after submit call methods', () => {
service.callNextFunction.and.returnValue(of({value: 0}));

const result = new FormGroup({}, )
result.setValidators(null);
spyOn(component.dialogWindow, 'open')
  .and
  .returnValue({
    afterClosed: () => of(true)
  } as MatDialogRef<typeof component>);
  
fixture.detectChanges();
expect(component.dialogWindow.afterAllClosed).toContain(result);
expect(service.callNextFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
expect(component.otherForm.recommendedValue.control.value).toEqual('123');
```

});

but when I test it I am getting error:

```
Error: <spyOn> : open has already been spied upon
Usage: spyOn(<object>, <methodName>)
```

can it be caused by create:

```
matDialogSpy = createSpyObj<MatDialog>('MatDialog', ['open']);
```

in beforeEach?
I use matDialogSpy  in other unit test for check if dialog window will open after click on button:

```
it('should open dialog when button has been clicked', fakeAsync(() => {
clickOnSlsButtonByLabel('Open dialog', fixture);

expect(matDialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
expect(matDialogSpy.open).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
  PollComponent,
  {
    width: '400px',
    height: '400px',
    data: data...
  }
);
```

}));

Answer (score 0):

Exception is self explainatory - it is already as spy, just use it

Bare in mind that you should replace `component.dialogWindow` with whatever you have provided as as `MatDialog` in your test

```
component.dialogWindow.open //maybe matDialogSpy.open??
  .and
  .returnValue({
    afterClosed: () => of(true)
  } as MatDialogRef<typeof component>);
```

Comment: Thanks, this error is resolved but I am not sure if I use `afterClosed` correctly. How should I mock `dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe` (in ts file) to get declered in spec.ts `result`?

Comment: `afterClosed: () =>of(yourExpectedResultHere)` and `afterClosedAll` is not `afterClosed` and you are not configuring the first one anywhere I can see.That is a topic for different question.

Comment: What do you mean with `afterClosedAll` ?  Its about call on `expect(component.dialogWindow.afterAllClosed).toContain(result);` ? Would you like to edit your answer and add a little more code?